# Relationship between smooth manifold and differentiable manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, sheaf-theory

Define a smooth manifold to be a ringed space (a Hausdorff, second countable, $n$-manifold) that is locally isomorphic (as a ringed space) to the sheaf of *smooth* real valued functions on some open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Similarly, a differentiable manifold is a ringed $n$-manifold locally isomorphic to the sheaf of *differentiable* real valued functions on some open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. **EDIT**: I should also mention the sections of these sheafs are actually real valued functions defined on the open subsets of the space.

I believe I've been told that the two notions are actually equivalent; that is, a differentiable structure can be shown to be smooth. I've heard this is a difficult result.

Comment: whoops fixed that

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225528/differentiable-manifolds-as-locally-ringed-spaces.

Comment: Nope that are not the same. We use the term $n$-fold continuously differentiable function, or simply $C^n$-map. And a smooth map is a $C^\infty$ map. And for distinct $n,m\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$, the category of $C^n$ manifold and the category of $C^m$ manifold are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding of the relationship, not being a geometer I fully expect to be either told off for misuse of language or supplanted through a better explanation of key concepts.

A differentiable manifold equipped with an equivalence class of atlases whose transition functions are all *differentiable*. A smooth manifold is a differentiable manifold equipped with *smooth* transition maps. That is to say; the deriviatives of all orders exists (i.e., it is a $C^{k}$ manifold).

For my purposes, the relations rests on this transition map 'equivalence'.

Comment: Isn't this distinction exactly the same as the one I stressed in my definition, just in atlas parlance?

Comment: Yes it is - I think we have the same understanding. The notion of equivalence between the two is hard to prove if memory serves me correctly; I think is rests on the discovery of every *local smooth extension* of the transition maps near every point in the domain.

Comment: to clarify, "the notion of equivalence" you are referring to is the equivalence between 'smooth' and 'differentiable and not simply the equivalence of the atlas of charts and ringed space definitions, right?

Comment: @basket Yes that is correct, apologies, convoluted use of language!